# Maximum row insert limit | execute_values Command | Postgres

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql

How many rows I can insert in single time with `execute_values` command in Postgres database? I am using latest PostgreSQL (version 12) and executing this command in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many rows you insert in PostgreSQL query
If you're simply filtering the data and data fits in memory, Postgres is capable of parsing roughly 5-10 million rows per second (assuming some reasonable row size of say 100 bytes). If you're aggregating then you're at about 1-2 million rows per second

so if you insert multiple data in table use COPY COMMAND

```
\COPY world_pop FROM 'C:\Users\Kashif\data.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',' WITH (FORMAT CSV ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably is limited by the amount of RAM. But rather than creating huge statements, use `COPY` and stream the data to the server.